# JQuery link button does not work returned from PHP, but does work if not

Tags: php, json, jquery

I have a button that does not work in jquery. A button is passed from php to Jquery using json object. I have removed all other code just the button to test to try and solve this.
I create the same link and place it on my page in php. when the link is clicked a alert appears and works.

On the same page I have an additional button which is the same button, but this button has been returned from PHP via json to Jquery and 
appended to the div. This link/button does not work? why is this? both appear the same!

Hope someone can advise as to what is happening here

Thanks

button returned from PHP

```
   //Jquery basic test button for functionality (works if link button is already on HTML page)
    $("[href='#test']").click(function() {      
    alert("has been clicked");
    });

//JQuery extract of my code 

var content;
$.each(data, function(i, item) {
content += item;

});
$(content).appendTo('#theframe');
},'json');
```

have also tried

```
$.each(data, function(i, item) {
content += item;

});
$('#theframe').html(content);
},'json');




//php returned
$json[] = '<a href="#test">View Post</a>';
echo json_encode($json);

//php button on page
<a href="#test">View Post</a>
```

Thanks

SOLVED with help from all posts, thank you! @Anthony's example added the frame 
     $('#theframe').on('click', '[href="#test"]', function(e) {
    alert('has been clicked');
    });

Comment: Thanks who posted a response, thanks for the explanations I have learned a lot ;) thanks. @Anthony I have used your example worked great thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `.click()` function only adds the event handler to elements that exist when the code is run, so won't affect any elements that are added dynamically later on. The easiest solution to get around this is to set up event delegation, using either the [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) (jQuery 1.7+) or [`.delegate()`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) (prior to 1.7) functions. The `.on()` example would look like this:

```
$('body').on('click', '[href="#test"]', function(e) {
    alert('has been clicked');
});
```

Comment: Thanks for everyone who posted a response, thanks for the explanations I have learned a lot ;) thanks. @Anthony I have used your example worked great thanks

Answer (score 3):

You will need to use the jQuery on() or delegate() functions to add the click event to new page elements that are added dynamically (after the page is loaded).

If you are using jQuery 1.7 and greater you should use on(): http://api.jquery.com/on/

If you are using an older version of jQuery use delegate: http://api.jquery.com/delegate/

Answer (score 1):

the reason it does not work is that your document ready function only fires once. This means that after your second button loads via ajax, there is no event handler attached to it.

Try using "on" or "live":

```
$("body").on("click", a[href="#target"], function(event){
alert("has been clicked");
});
```

http://api.jquery.com/on/ <- Docs for "on"

http://api.jquery.com/ <- Your new favorite website!

Hope this helps!

Comment: That `.on()` syntax is equivalent to what they already have - they need to use the event delegation syntax. Also, `.live()` is deprecated - no reason to use it unless you're using a version of jQuery so old it doesn't event have `.delegate()`.